# Is there a way to handle files within google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, zip

There are many compressed files inside google cloud storage.

I want to unzip the zipped file, rename it and save it back to another bucket.

I've seen a lot of posts, but I couldn't find a way other than how to download it with gsutil and handle it.

Do you have any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify a file, such as unzipping, you must read, modify and then write. This means download, unzip and upload the extracted files.

Use gsutil or another tool, one of the SDKs, or the REST APIs. To unzip a file, use a zip tool or one of the libraries that support zip operations.

Comment: I thought I could access the inside of GCS from the cloud shell, but it seems impossible. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using cloudFunctions for it. CloudFunction will get [triggered](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers) when the object is created/finalized and it will do the job automatically.

You can also use the same function to iterate over all the zip files, do the tasks and move same files to another bucket. One thing to make sure it may not be able to move all files in a single go, but for the files which already exists on the bucket, you can use local machine to run the program.

Here is the list of libraries to [connect to CloudStorage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries)

Comment: I also tried connecting, decompressing, and uploading GCS in python, but I found that uploading took a lot longer than I thought.
Currently, we are trying to apply cloudfunction and dataflow functions by comparing them.